# How to check if a environment variable is set with 'set -o nounset' ?

Tags: shell

In bash/zsh, the following check for checking a variable doesn't work:

```
#!/bin/zsh

set -o nounset # Error when unset vars are used
set -o errexit 

if [ -n ${foo-x} ]; then
  echo "Foo exists!"
else
  echo "Foo doesn't exist"
fi
```

Because foo is expanded even if it doesn't exist, nounset triggers, and it exits. How can I check the existence of a variable without expanding it? I really like nounset and errexit, so I'd rather not disable them halfway each time I want to check if some var is set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a function for the check (and turn of the `nounset` only in the function), call the function with the variable name and use the indirect variable referencing. something like the next:

```
set -o nounset
set -o errexit

isset() {
    set +o nounset
    [[ -n "${!1+x}" ]]
    result=$?
    set -o nounset
    return $result
}

a=1
#call the "isset" with the "name" not value, so "a" and not "$a"
isset a && echo "a is set" || echo "a isnt set"

b=''
isset b && echo "b is set" || echo "b isnt set"

isset c && echo "c is set" || echo "c isnt set"
```

prints:

```
a is set
b is set
c isnt set
```

## EDIT

Just learned a clean method, use the `-v varname` (need bash 4.2+ or zsh 5.3+)

```
[[ -v a ]] && echo "a ok" || echo "a no"
[[ -v b ]] && echo "b ok" || echo "b no"
[[ -v c ]] && echo "c ok" || echo "c no"
```

Comment: @Nick added an simpler and clean method without a function.

Comment: Until bash 5.1 `-v` does not work with positional arguments like `${1}`

Comment: For posterity, since these kind of references are not super easy to search for: ‘-v’ is documented in the Bash Reference Manual under section 6.4, “Bash Conditional Expressions”. https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions